# ifort 64 bit build; ifort 64 vs. gfortran 64

Tags: performance, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have what I imagine will be an easy question.  How do I create a 64-bit build using ifort?  I'm using "ifort -Ofast -o program.exe *.f*".  I've set the compilervars to intel64 and am working on win7 using a xeon processor.  I've looked through the menu of compiler flags but haven't been able to identify what I need.  I see there's a -m64 option for mac users but that won't help me.

A second question, would there be that big of a performance issue between a gfortran -m64 build relative to the same using ifort?

Thanks!

Comment: For your second question: All my experiments show that both compilers perform comparable, with gfortran being slightly faster most of the time (gcc 4.8.2 vs. ifort 14.0.1). But, as always, it depends on your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ifort, you need to invoke the ifortvars.sh (or .csh) script with the "intel64" argument to get the x64 compiler. In fact, you are required to specify that argument (either as intel64 or ia32), so look to see how it is invoked in your environment and fix the reference. This is not selected with an option to the ifort command.

As for performance comparisons, I would point you at [Polyhedron](http://polyhedron.com/), an independent software reseller in the UK. They do multi-compiler comparisons on fixed hardware. Click on "Compiler Comparisons" in the left column. In their tests, gfortran is in 5th place (ifort is 1st).